# Regular validation expression for Address

Tags: asp.net

```
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
        ID="RegularExpressionValidatoradd" runat="server" ValidationExpression=""  ControlToValidate="textboxadd" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid address!" >  
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

i do not want these characters ~`!@$%^*+=}{[]":;?><  in my  textboxadd.Now what should i write in ValidationExpression=""

Comment: Question: Which characters would you allow ?

Comment: 1234567890 a-z A-Z / #&()_-\.,/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
        ID="RegularExpressionValidatoradd" runat="server" ValidationExpression="\d{1,5}\s\w.\s(\b\w*\b\s){1,2}\w*\."  ControlToValidate="textboxadd" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid address!" >  
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

**(or)**

```
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
            ID="RegularExpressionValidatoradd" runat="server" ValidationExpression="[0-9a-zA-Z #,-]+"  ControlToValidate="textboxadd" ErrorMessage="Enter Valid address!" >  
        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```